# SQLite delete from table where field does not match an object in an array

Tags: arrays, sqlite, mysql

Say I have a table with an `ID` field, and I have a local array (in any language, php or objective c or basic or whatever) of eligible `ID`s. I want to delete any record in which the `ID` field does not match any of the eligible `ID`s in my array.

Is there any way to do this in a single SQL query? Can you pass an array into SQL and basically say `delete from sometable where 'id' is not in 'arrayofids'`?

Thanks for any help. I've looked into the help docs but SQLite/SQL aren't one of my best skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've already found the answer:

```
$locationSQL = "DELETE * FROM item WHERE 'ID' NOT IN ($somearray)";
```

And you simply use commas to separate the items of the array. Simple enough.

Comment: The character '*' is not valid in SQLite.